# Config webpack with Request

Tags: request, webpack

at the moment i try to implement request with webpack, apparently its not straight forward i have implemented the following stubbing method form link below:

https://github.com/request/request/issues/1529

```
node: {
        console: false,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
```

Now the build is successful but i getting this following error in da browser and noting shows up:

```
Uncaught Error: define cannot be used indirect
```

any one have experience to successfully implement Uncaught Error: define cannot be used indirect with webpack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ npm install --save request@2.65.0 solved the problem for me :)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11166856)

Comment: @stackptr do you see a 'thank you' there? obviously i put up the answer because there are ppl maybe struggling the same...

Comment: Installed 'request@2.65.0', but still experiencing the same problem.. :(

Comment: @C.Lee try to delete your node_modules folder and do a clean npm i :)

Comment: thanks for your reply @bluebill1049, but that didn't work for me either. I'll keep looking

Comment: And do we know **why** does 2.65.0 solves this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack with ES6 then I would recommend trying a library designed for ES6, such as https://github.com/alexrsagen/node-es6-request.